# Mounting an EXT4 partition that is marked as RAID 0xFD

Tags: mdadm

I have one hard drive, with a GPT partition table and three partitions.  One partition is SWAP.  The other two partitions are marked as LINUX RAID 0xFD, but one of them should be an EXT4 file system.  How can I mount that EXT4 partition to copy data off?

Answer (score 0):

sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
(if it had been part of a RAID1-setup). Then a device /dev/md??? should appear.

Otherwise use

cat /proc/mdstat

maybe the RAID is already active.

Comment: `/proc/mdstat` has `personalities=raid1`, and also `md127:active[auto-read-only] raid1 sdb3[0]` and `3902196544 blocks super 1.2 [1/1] [U]` and `unused devices: <none>`

Comment: `/dev/md127` already exists with this one hard disk connected, I am using SLES 12.3, and `mdadm --assemble --scan` returns `no arrays found in config file or automatically`